# Realizar um DELETE com where sendo o resultado de um SELECT (MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

Galera, tenha um código no qual uso o resultado de um SELECT para ser condição no WHERE de um DELETE.

Vou deixar a parte do código para ver se vcs conseguem observar algum erro. 
O UPDATE (que fica na parte de cima do código) funciona, porém a parte do DELETE no final não está dando resultado.

```
<?php

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

    // CHAMANDO O ARQUIVO DE CONEXÃO AO BANCO
    require_once("../conexao/conexao-com-banco.php"); 

    //CONSULTA NO BANCO QUE MUDA O STATUS NO BANCO DE DADOS 


    session_start();

    $usuario = $_SESSION["nome"];

    //$estate = $_POST['estate'];

    $tipo_atividade = $_POST['tipoatividade'];
    $codi = $_POST['codigo'];
    $cod = $_POST['cod'];

    $data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");


    $inserirStandBy = "UPDATE tbl_atividades set CONFERENCIA = 'STANDY BY', DETALHES = CONCAT(IFNULL(DETALHES, 'Atualizações:'), 'ATIVIDADE PARA POR FALTA DE ARQUIVOS'), STATUS = 'STAND_BY', ATUALIZADO = 'S', DT_INICIO = NULL, DT_FIM = NULL WHERE codigo = $codi";
    $resultado_update_stand = mysqli_query($conecta, $inserirStandBy);


    $select_data = "SELECT DT_VENCIMENTO FROM tbl_atividades WHERE codigo = $codi";
    $result_select_stand = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conecta, $select_data));

    $dt_vencimento = $result_select_stand['DT_VENCIMENTO'];



    $deletar_atividades = "DELETE FROM tbl_atividades WHERE TIPO_ATIVIDADE = '$tipo_atividade' AND COD = '$cod' AND DT_VENCIMENTO > $dt_vencimento";
    $result_delete_stand = mysqli_query($conecta, $deletar_atividades);

?>
```

OBS: O resultado do SELECT é um campo DATE.

Só estou postando a parte do código em PHP, acho que não seja necessária a parte do AJAX.

Desde já, agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Já tentou fazer um pequeno teste printando manualmente o resultado da sua variável que recebeu o SELECT e depois tentando realizar esse delete manualmente pra ver se o problema não está no valor contido na variável ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O resultado da evocação à função `mysqli_query` não é um valor escalar, mas sim objeto do tipo `mysqli_result` ([PHP: mysqli::query - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)).

---

O que precisa fazer é obter o valor da data para depois utilizar no `DELETE` a seguir, desta forma:

```
$select_data = "SELECT DT_VENCIMENTO FROM tbl_atividades WHERE codigo = $codi";
$result_select_stand = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conecta, $select_data));

$dt_vencimento = $result_select_stand['DT_VENCIMENTO'];

$deletar_atividades = "DELETE FROM tbl_atividades WHERE TIPO_ATIVIDADE = '$tipo_atividade' AND COD = '$cod' AND DT_VENCIMENTO > '$dt_vencimento'";
$result_delete_stand = mysqli_query($conecta, $deletar_atividades);
```

Comment: Olá, João. Realizei as alterações aqui, mas o DELETE não foi executado. Os dados que chegam do formulário, via AJAX, estão chegando, pois o primeiro UPDATE do código funciona normalmente. Você, por um acaso, não saberia se pode haver outro problema relacionado ao meu código ?

Comment: Se fizer um `echo $dt_vencimento` o que lhe é devolvido? Experimente colocar a data entre plicas: `DT_VENCIMENTO > '$dt_vencimento'`.

Comment: João Martins, era mesmos as plicas (aspas). Adicionei isso e seu código funcionou. Mas a variável é um campo tipo DATE. Você saberia me explicar o por quê de usar aspas em variável que guardam dados to tipo DATE ? Altera lá sua resposta que vou aceitá-la. Valeu!

Comment: Resposta editada. Sim, apesar de ser do tipo `DATE`, é necessário colocar as plicas para que seja entendido como texto, caso contrário será apenas números com um separador, algo que não é aceite pelo compilador.

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução é incluir esse primeiro SELECT como um sub-select da função DELETE. Ex.:

```
$deletar_atividades = "DELETE FROM tbl_atividades WHERE TIPO_ATIVIDADE = '$tipo_atividade' AND COD = '$cod' AND DT_VENCIMENTO > (SELECT DT_VENCIMENTO FROM tbl_atividades WHERE codigo = $codi LIMIT 0, 1)";
$result_delete_stand = mysqli_query($conecta, $deletar_atividades);
```

Comment: Também tentei da sua forma, Diego Marques, mas também não deu certo.